# Protobuf-Net as copy constructor

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

is it possible to create a generic copy constructor based on protobuf-net?
Something like:

```
   public class Person
   {
      public Int32 Id { get; set; }

      public String FirstName { get; set; }

      public Int32 Age { get; set; }

      public String Name { get; set; }
   }


   public static void DeepCopyCosntructor<T>(T source, T target)
   {
      // copy all properties by protobuf-net
   }
```

I want to avoid reflection, but I don't know how to fill the properties of target without recreating a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue to consider here is the "merge" semantics as defined by the protobuf specification. You'd be fine for *basic properties*, but for *collections and dictionaries*, the default behaviour is to *add*, not *replace*. So, you'd need to add the usual protobuf-net attributes, *and* make sure that every collection is set to overwrite:

```
[ProtoMember(n, OverwriteList = true)]
```

Again, I'm not sure this is the best use-case for protobuf-net, but: a merge can be done by passing in `target`; so with the v1 API:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize<T>(ms, source);
    ms.Position = 0;
    target = Serializer.Merge<T>(ms, target);
}
```

or in the v2 API:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize(ms, source);
    ms.Position = 0;
    target = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(ms, target, typeof(T));
}
```

Note that in both cases the `target =` is primarily to handle the scenario where `target` is initially `null`.

Comment: Thanks for that! One question to the 'OverwriteList': I would like  to use protobuf-net for all my classes, and because I don't want to always specify the attributes I would like to do it over 'RuntimeTypeModel'. So is it worse to always set 'OverwriteList' to true?

Comment: @Franki1986 not "worse" - just different; it will have the effect of meaning you can't use "append===merge with append", which is the behaviour specified by Google's implementation. If you don't care about that: have fun