# Mapping complex objects with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

Im making a function that maps two diferent objects (with equivalent properties and types) using reflection and generic objects (T). My function works well with objects with simple properties like int or string types but now I have to add support for object properties or lists wihtin an object. Can I do this recursively or is it not posible ? I can't post the code for work reasons.
The active code is the following:

```
    public static T MapObjects<T>(object sourceObject) where T : new()
    {
        T destObject = new T();

        Type sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
        Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in sourceType.GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo targetObj = targetType.GetProperty(p.Name);
            if (targetObj == null)
                continue;

            targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
        }
        return destObject;
    }
```

Can I modify this function to call itself when the property is an object ?

Comment: You can post your own, non-work, sample code so we can see what you've got so far. The majority of questions without any code get closed for the reason "too broad" or something like "questions about 'why isn't this code working' must include code".

Comment: This question is very vague without code. What specifically do you wish to do recursively? Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Why not use AutoMapper?

Comment: Second vote for automapper

Comment: You are asking: Can I modify the code to call itself: Why do you not simply try that and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Protobuf.net (which can be installed as Nuget package). It is based on Google protocol buffer and is fairly easy to serialize and deserialise objects or copy objects.

[Protobuf-Net as copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058718/protobuf-net-as-copy-constructor)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serialization-and-deserialization-ib-c-sharp-using-protobuf-dll/

[Getting started with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535913/getting-started-with-protobuf-net)

Comment: The problem with this answer, is its just a link to a nuget package, with no reference to how it solves the problem

Comment: Added a link for stackoverflow. I can provide a sample code if ud like